# Получение DOM из Chromium Embedded Framework

Tags: c++, google-chrome, webkit

Я использую CEF для получения DOM дерева HTML страницы и в последствии изъятия из неё свойств элементов (ширина, высота, отступы и т.д.). Проблема в том, что CEF возвращает только свойства, заданные через HTML, но не через CSS файлы. Как это исправить?